# Ordering the Display in AMPL

Tags: ampl

I'm doing a model for the scheduling problem, I already solved it, but I want to order the output, by crescent numbers. This is my output, where X[i] is the time of the beginning of the job i.

```
x [*] :=
NM2646FX-1024  109.5
 NM2646FX-107  138.3
NM2646FX-1115  120.3
 NM2646FX-176  213.3
 NM2646FX-220  180.3
  NM2646FX-81  220.8
 NM2646FX-999  285.9
RD1060FX-2144   68.1
RD1060FX-3854   34.5
 RD720FX-1515    0
  RD720FX-878  237.9
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, the only type of model entity that can be easily sorted in AMPL is `set`. Sorting parameters is trickier. You can create an ordered `set` and assign the values of your `x` variables to it:

```
set xOrderedSet ordered by Reals;
let xOrderedSet := setof {i in S} x[i].val;
display xOrderedSet;
```

I believe this will only work if all x's are unique. Then you can create a param `xOrdered` to map the values with its respective set entry:

```
param xOrdered{xOrderedSet} symbolic;

for {i in xOrderedSet} {
    let {s in S : i = x[s].val} xOrdered[i] := s;
}

display xOrdered;
```

More info on the `let` command [here](https://pifop.com/help/ampl_basic_commands.html#Modifying%20Model%20Entities).